# Should the rvalue be valid after a move?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue

Lets say we have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() { _bar=new Bar };
    Foo(const Foo &right) { _bar=new Bar(right.bar); };
    Foo(Foo &&right) { _bar=right._bar;  right.bar=new Bar(); };

    ~Foo() { delete _bar; }

    Foo &operator=(const Foo &right) { _bar->opertor=(right.bar); return *this;}
    Foo &operator=(Foo &&right) { std::swap(_bar, right._bar); return *this;}

    void func() { _bar->test=1 };

private:
    Bar *_bar;
};
```

is it legitimate to alter it to the following and expect the end user to know that after the move is performed that the rvalue is no longer valid (in that calling anything other than the assignment operator could crash)?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() { _bar=new Bar };
    Foo(const Foo &right) { _bar=new Bar(right.bar); };
    Foo(Foo &&right) { _bar=right._bar;  right.bar=nullptr; };

    ~Foo() { if(_bar != nullptr) delete _bar; }

    Foo &operator=(const Foo &right) 
    { 
         if(_bar == nullptr) 
             _bar=new Bar();
         _bar->opertor=(right.bar); 
         return *this;
    }

    Foo &operator=(Foo &&right)
    {
        if(_bar != nullptr)
            delete _bar;  
        _bar=right._bar; 
        right._bar=nullptr; 
        return *this;
    }

    void func() { _bar->test=1 };

private:
    Bar *_bar;
};
```

my concern comes from the fact that func (and all other functions in the class) assume that _bar exists.

Comment: fixed typos and added null checks to operator=

Comment: The edit substantially changes the question. Previously it would dereference a null pointer if they used `operator=` after the move; we thought you were asking whether the move is OK anyway and the calling code should know to avoid doing that.   But now the object is valid after the move and it is unclear what your question is (in both cases the object is valid now).  Please edit again to clarify your intent

Comment: I may have asked it wrong but for me the question is the same, given the following code snippet `Foo a,b; a=std::move(b); b.func();`. the top implementation will not crash, behavior is likely undesirable but it wont crash. Under the new implementation calling b.func() after the move will cause a crash. The question then is it legitimate to expect that the user should know that calling anything other than operator= on b, after the move, could crash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In principle it may become invalid, though you might want consider leaving it in an assignable state (which your original implementation, hence edited, did not do). This would follow the policy of the standard library, which says:

> Unless otherwise specified, all standard library objects that have been moved from are placed in a valid but unspecified state. That is, only the functions without preconditions, such as the assignment operator, can be safely used on the object after it was moved from

I'd recommend reimplementing the assignment operator such that it swaps "this" object with a newly constructed one. This is generally a good way to avoid introducing incorrect behaviour when implementing assignments.

Comment: what about altering it to just this `Foo &operator=(const Foo &other) { if(_bar == nullptr) _bar=new Bar(); _bar->opertor=(right.bar); return *this;}` and `Foo &operator=(Foo &&other) { if(_bar != nullptr) delete _bar;  _bar=right._bar; right._bar=nullptr; return *this;}`

Comment: You could do that if you really want to avoid unnecessary allocations in assignments to empty `Foo` objects, but have you confirmed that's not premature optimisation? And if that is the case, you could instead consider having the default constructor not do `new Bar`, which is the only case where a "superfluous" `Bar` object would normally get allocated. It depends on your use case for this class.

Comment: I think the default constructor has to have the allocation as none of the class functions expect _bar to be a nullptr. Without the allocation user who created `Foo foo;` and then called `foo.func();` would crash. This is less of an optimization than for the code to do what is "expected". Lets assume Bar is 20MB and I create `Foo a, b;` I would expect 40MB+ to be used however later when I set `a=b;` I am expecting only 20MB to be in use as b should be empty now. The top case will not do that.

Comment: It really depends on what semantic you want the `Foo` object to have, and there is no universally correct answer to that. For reference, a `std::shared_ptr` is invalid if default constructed and will throw an exception if dereferenced in that state. Either way, following the "principle of least surprise", I would have made it behave the same way when moved from as when default constructed.

Answer (score 6):

A moved-from object is supposed to be in a *valid but unspecified state*.  Note that this is a recommendation but not an absolute requirement of the standard.

Your second code will break if a normal operation is performed on it afterwards (specifically, the copy-assignment operator).

If `_bar == nullptr` is a valid state then your copy-assignment operator is bugged;  if it is not a valid state then I would say your move-constructor is bugged.

NB. In the second code, the `if` check in the destructor is redundant, as it is legal to delete a null pointer.

Comment: Note: The question has been edited since this answer was posted - please check original edit history

Answer (score 0):

> is it legitimate to alter it to the following and expect the end user to know that after the move is performed that the rvalue is no longer valid?

You should certainly do that. An rvalue reference is not supposed be kept in an usable state. The idea behind the move constructors and move assignment operators is that you are *moving* the useful data from the object. I wouldn't use *no longer valid* to describe it though. It is still a valid object from a C++ point of view just like `nullptr` is a valid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The second version is more idiomatic. After an object is moved from it is assumed it will no longer be used.

The check for `nullptr` before calling `delete` on the pointer is unnecessary as it is defined in the standard to do nothing.

If the user wishes to use the moved from object, it is his job to make sure it is in a valid state (i.e. assigning from a valid object).

Answer (score 0):

You should document for your `Foo` what preconditions each member function has, for example:

```
void Foo::func();
```

> *Requires:*  `*this` is not in a moved-from state.

Then you're good to go for any of your clients that need to use `Foo::func()`, unless...

If you use `Foo` with someone else's library that requires `func()`, and does not document something along the lines of "except when in a moved-from state", then you're out of luck.

For example:  Let's say that your `Foo` has a `operator<` like this:

```
bool operator<(const Foo& x, const Foo& y);
```

> *Requries:* Neither `x` nor `y` may be in a moved-from state.

Now if you do something like:

```
std::vector<Foo> v;
// ... fill v
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());  // oops!
```

The last line above requires `Foo` to be `LessThanComparable` *whether or not `Foo` is in a moved-from state*.  And this is true of *all* of the generic code in the std::lib.  The requires clauses for std code apply to user-supplied code and do not make exceptions for moved-from objects.

However, if your `operator<` works when either argument is in a moved-from state, then the call to `std::sort` is fine.  This is true even if `func()` still has the requirement that `Foo` *not* be in a moved-from state.  This is because `std::sort` doesn't require `func()` to work at all.

So in summary, it all depends on what other code your `Foo` interacts with.  Maybe it is ok, and maybe it is not.  Document what `Foo` does, and understand the requirements of the code you use `Foo` with.